# Remove blinking cursor for web screenshot test

Tags: javascript, webdriver

I have the following case: create screenshot of the current page and compare it with golden one.

Problem: Focused field is required and it has blinking cursor.
Test is not stable.

What I did try:

1) remove focus -> field is required and I have error message

2) hide element -> works but element becomes not visible and we don't check UI things for this field

3) Put white rectangle on top of the field -> unfortunately I don't control image file, it's inside of libs that I cannot modify

What I'd like to do:
make cursor white or transparent w/o changing input field.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you try color: white?

Comment: I don't see such property here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: No I mean style for text input.

Comment: Let me try something like input:focus { color: yellow }

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me

Comment: Cursor is still black and blinking

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the following style to the body element:

`caret-color: transparent`

before taking a screenshot

Comment: @stryba why you tag me?

Comment: @UttamNath because your comment made no sense